# Finding the factors of integer $x$ and its square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

What is the the theorem or property that says that $\forall{}x\in\Bbb Z$, the set of all integers, $x^2$ has the same factors as $x$, twice?

Comment: ...I think you could imply it through the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic

Comment: Also known as, the Unique Factorization Theorem.

Comment: You mean, the same *prime* factors.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the *property* may be the following: let
$$
x={p_1}^{a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot{p_n}^{a_n}
$$
be the [**unique** factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) of $x\in\Bbb Z$, $x>1$, then
$$
x^2=\left({p_1}^{a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot{p_n}^{a_n}\right)^2=
{p_1}^{2a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot{p_n}^{2a_n}.
$$

Comment: Thanks @shardulc for proofreading ;)

Answer (score 0):

The correct statement is

> For every integer $x$, $x^2$ has the same prime factors as $x$.

This follows immediately from this key fact about primes:

> If $p$ is a prime and $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.

Indeed, if $p$ divides $x$, then $p$ divides $xx=x^2$. Conversely, if $p$ divides $x^2=xx$, then $p$ divides $x$.